# JNI NewStringUTF crashes in android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

```
A/art(30231): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'LevelScore11�
 art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] '
 art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF   
A/art(16684): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender()
     A/art(16684): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 003e93f8  /data/app/com.xxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv12NewStringUTFEPKc+40)
     art/runtime/check_jni.`enter code here`cc:65]   native: #09 pc 003efc8c  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_Z19setIntegerForKeyJNIPKci+112)
     art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 005cd8b8  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d11UserDefault16setIntegerForKeyEPKci+40)
     art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 003d62a8  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (???)
     art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 004553f4  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d8CallFunc7executeEv+156)
     art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #13 pc 0045534c  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d8CallFunc6updateEf+40)
```

For many files I am getting error to call in

> NewStringUTF function

APP being crash at this function.

Does it any newer version available? I have found so many solution but no luck . Can any one help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the entire JNI call that u created and its causing this crash so we can see what you have done.

Comment: @IulianVărzaru i am unable to find which file causing error

Comment: The 13rd character is not an utf8 character and therefore crashes the NewStringUTF function. Try to dump the char* before creating the String.

Comment: @SimonMarquis how can i dump it ? any option ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from your error and because you are not doing anything else with JNI it seems that the error is happening when you are trying to save an integer to UserDefaults:

```
A/art(16684): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 003e93f8  /data/app/com.xxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv12NewStringUTFEPKc+40)
     art/runtime/check_jni.`enter code here`cc:65]   native: #09 pc 003efc8c  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_Z19setIntegerForKeyJNIPKci+112)
     art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 005cd8b8  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d11UserDefault16setIntegerForKeyEPKci+40
```

So check where you are calling UserDefault to setIntegerForKey if you somehow put an string instead of an int, it should be:

```
cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance()->setIntegerForKey("key", 0);
```

or if you want to save an string:

```
cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance()->setStringForKey("userCards", "value);
```

**UPDATE**

Ok try this and post the result here so we can see exactly what is happening:

```
cd $ANDROID_NDK
adb logcat | ./ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi
```

where:

**$ANDROID_NDK** is the path to your android NDK

**$PROJECT_PATH** is the path to your cocos2d-x android project

Comment: thak you for help. but I haven't setting any string in  **setIntegerForKey** . Also error might be encoding in UTF-8 , but unable to find solution yet.

Can you tell where can I found my **check_jni .cc** file ?

Comment: You are saving anything to UserDefaults ?

Comment: yes I am saving value in UserDefaults  and I am saving integer value in setIntegerForKey.. i am not saving any string in setIntegerForKey.

Comment: dunno without seeing your actual code or parts where you save to UserDefaults or any other JNI calls I cannot say exactly what its your problem.